# How to set the UTF-8 as default encoding in Odoo Build?

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, odoo-8

Can anyone tell me how to set the **UTF-8** as **default encoding** option in **Odoo Build**.?

**Note :** I have mentioned "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" in all the files which takes no effect on my expected encoding.

Comment: add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> in your xml

Answer (score 0):

If you put `# coding: utf-8` at the top of a Python module, this affects the way how Python interprets the **source code**. This is important if you have string literals with non-ASCII characters in your code, in order to have them represent the correct characters.

However, since you talk about "default encoding", I assume you care about the encoding of **text files** opened for reading or writing. In Python 2.x, the default for reading and writing files is *not to decode/encode* at all. I don't think you can change this default (because the built-in function `open` simply doesn't support encoding), **but** you can use `io.open()` or `codecs.open()` to open files with an explicit encoding.

Thus, to read from a file encoded with UTF-8, open it as follows:

```
with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

In Python 3, built-in `open()` is the same as `io.open()`, and the default encoding is platform-dependent.

Comment: Dear Lenz, let me rephrase or detail my question. I do manipulate the texts through my code. the code which works fine in development Environment, shows encoding error (due to Non-Ascii charactors) while running ODOO BUILD. And i do read the text from database.

Comment: @ganesheverbest I suggest you update your post with these details: show us the code you use (try to [keep it short](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and describe clearly the circumstances in which it works and in which it doesn't.